# Webapp shown twice once started

Tags: unity, chromium, webapps

I added a few webapps to my starter panel and if I start one of it the chromium icon appears below of it. Chromium itself is locked to the starter separately, that means that once I start the webapp I got `2x` chromium icons in my starter (see screenshot)

Can someone tell me if it is possible to disable that the second chromium icon is shown once I've started a webapp ?

[image]

Comment: This happens for me with thunderbird and only that.

Comment: I got same same issue with Chromium. Did you find a solution?